# Application design and required stored procedure conventions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle

First some background,

I am currently working on a relatively large Asp.Net MVC application that I have tried, as much as possible, to design around a domain driven model, using good design principles. We are required to do all database access via stored procedures (Oracle).  In this application, I have a variety of controllers that use service objects to do business logic and in turn call on repository objects to accomplish access.

I have just been informed that the dba requires several common parameters to be passed to every stored procedure in addition to the parameters required to fetch/update/insert the data.  These parameters include the username, ip address and domain of the user making the original web request.  This data is then used in by each stored procedure to call functions that log access and check that the user has permissions to execute that particular stored procedure.

I have tried to gently explain that I feel this is poor design and that the .Net application could simply call stored procedures dedicated to logging and checking permissions whenever necessary.  Unfortunately, this methodology is well established in the environment and the dba is unwilling to change it.

So now to my question,

Does anyone have any good ideas on how I can accomplish retrieving these extra parameters and deliver them to the repository objects without making a huge mess?  From what I can tell this data is only available from the web context when in the controller layer.  This means passing the extra data to class in the service layer and then on to each repository class.  I'd like to minimize the pain here as much as possible.

Comment: If I was the DBA I would have been unwilling to change as well.  The problem with letting the app decide when is that developers all too often decide to forgo little things like logging.  Also, yours is just one app in the bunch; what about the others that come along?  Kudos to your DBA for not budging.

Comment: Why is it that a developer is more likely to forgo "little things" like logging any more than a dba?  I think logging is very important.  The problem here is that logging at the stored procedure level is limited to the logic there.  What about logging requirements for logic outside of individual procedures?  A separate procedure for this purpose would allow for this as well.

Comment: Logging at the database level and with the database's logging mechanism centralizes the logs across applications and stands as a single system of record.

Comment: Of course it does, and I agree with you.  This doesn't mean the best way to accomplish this is by passing 4 extra parameters to every procedure.

Comment: I don't want to turn this into an argument that side tracks your perfectly valid question.. However, if the requirement is that all data access must be logged then the *absolute best place* to do this is as close to the data as possible.  Originating IP, User and domain are great.  For one thing it means that you have exactly one group to look at (your DBA's) if there is ever a question as to who accessed what.  Further, if you must log those details to a central location on every request anyway, then you may as well do so as part of your data request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using dependency injection (you are aren't you - it is a larger project)
you can simply inject the service into the controller. The repository then is injected into the service. The repository's construction would take IUserSettings (or whatever its called) which is a concrete implementation of the details you require. Its then available to every repository.

```
public YourRepositoryClass(IUserSettings userSettings)
{
 _userSettings = userSettings;
}
```

and voila - its available.

Comment: I was using Spring.Net originally but was told no to 3rd party frameworks.  I have another thread about that though.

Comment: I may be missing something but this doesn't seem workable for my situation.  When is the concrete implementation of userSettings instantiated?  This would need to be done dynamically when the user makes a request.  Wouldn't this need to be injected into the repository when it is created?  This would be prior to the user request.

Comment: This would be injected at root of your object graph known as the 'composition root' which in this case is via constructor injection. since it seems you don't have your repositories in your controller (which is fine and preferred if using service classes) then you are injecting a service class via constructor injection. The service class then has constructors taking your other IWhatever items and your DI container populates all dependencies down the line. For example, it sees you need ISomeService and

Comment: you've defined a mapping to SomeService for ISomeService. Then it sees that SomeService has a constructor requiring ISomeRepository. It sees you have also setup a binding (mapping) for SomeRepository, so it instantiates that as wel, and so on down the object graph. Your settings you mentioned (username, ip address and domain of the user ) should all be available at the time of constructor instantiation.

Comment: btw if no 'third party' frameworks then simply use Unity. Since by default Unity doesn't dispose of objects per request, download the Unity.MVC3 package and that uses some code to allow for this. You do have to define in your mappings for any object you want disposed per request (ie specifically uses IDisposable) using the HierarchicalLifetimeManager

Comment: So a new repository object would be instantiated with the user info on every request?  I'm not sure to make this happen, but I will look into it.

Comment: 1. install unity.mvc3 nuget package  2. go into bootstraper.cs and define IUserSettings bind to UserSettings. 3. Add a constrtuctor to your controller that takes an ISomething you defined in step 2 to map to Something. The rest of the magic should happen automatically.

Comment: Where would I set the data on the UserSettings object?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7174/discussion-between-zaq-and-adam-tuliper)

Comment: Ok, this looks great using Unity.  They did tell me a while back no IOC containers of any kind but hopefully I can use this as a good reason to use one since they have this database requirement.

Comment: Why on earth for a larger system would someone not use an IOC container?

Comment: I really wish I could answer that one.  I had the whole thing setup with Spring and had to remove it because I mentioned it at a meeting.  Now it has Unity which I plan to keep quiet.

Comment: some companies have policies like you mentioned but thats the advantage in these cases with unity as its supported software from MS

Answer (score 1):

Have you asked the DBA to consider using `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO`?  You could then set it whenever allocating a connection to a user request, and then the DBA's logging procedure could read it.

Comment: We would need to create a separate stored procedure to call in order to populate it, would we not?

Comment: I'd argue not - it's already a stored procedure call.  `call dbms_application_info.set_client_info ('my_parseable_stuff_goes_here');`

Comment: Okay, I get it, it is a stored procedure itself.  I can't see this being allowed for the same reason I can't write a separate procedure and call it whenever a connection is allocated.

Comment: This isn't your procedure you're calling, it's Oracle's.  It's not accessing any of the underlying data under the app's purview.  Then he could adapt his logging code to use that data if it's populated, eliminating the need to force the developers to carry that data in every call.